# If i have two checkboxes yes or no how can i handle those two

Tags: jquery

If I have Two Check Boxes one is Yes another is No ,if i check on yes, no automatically uncheck(vise versa)
and saved into database (1 for yes 0 for no)

Comment: Use a radiobutton - it's all done for you.

Comment: @MikeW only if they have the same name. it's not right to say _it's all done for you_ just like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jquery u can make like this

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="2" name="fooby[1][]" />

<script>
       $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
            $(group).prop("checked",false);
            $(this).prop("checked",true);
        });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5EuS/1/ fiddle

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the recommended method for boolean attributes of elements (like `checked`) is `.prop()` rather than `.attr()`. I'm also pretty sure you want these two checkboxes to have different values, not both **1**.